# Javascript equivalent for converting character entities

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, html-entities, html-encode

I have the following html snippet with javascript embedded one-lined.

```
<div class="social_icon twitter" onclick="shareSocialWall('twitter','New Comment on xxxx - WTF, if the dancers don&amp;acirc;&amp;#128;&amp;#153;t come in until 4ish','https:/xxxx')"></div>
```

As you can see, theres an `onclick` event thats firing `shareSocialWall`. What's important here is the text `dancers don&amp;acirc;&amp;#128;&amp;#153;t`.

When the text gets passed to the function `shareSocialWall`, heres what happens:

```
 location='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+text+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(url);
```

The problem is that the text is breaking the call to perform this `tweet`. Is there a way to encode this text inside the javascript so it does not break the text.

The path for this text is:

```
- perl => encodes entities on comment text as xml node
- xslt => passes xml text to javascript function (uses disable output encoding which does nothing for this apparently)
- js => handles the text inside the shareSocialWall Function
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, the text has already been wrongfully encoded **twice** into html-entities when it ends up in JS. I have no experience with perl, and it's been forever since I dealt with xslt, but I'd recommend you to check that pipeline, and why and where the code gets encoded

Comment: @Thomas Yeh but technically if the text has been encoded once than the second one will be non mattering. im keeping it for design purposes to ensure all xslt xml elements usr that function but its just an empty call i suppose.

Comment: It matters, when it re-encodes the `&` of an entity as `&amp;` so that `&acirc;&#128;&#153;` becomes `&amp;acirc;&amp;#128;&amp;#153;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text seems to have been mangled already, probably incorrectly double encoded.

You could just remove all HTML entities with a regex:

```js
var str = 'New Comment on xxxx - WTF, if the dancers don&amp;acirc;&amp;#128;&amp;#153;t come in until 4ish';
console.log(str.replace(/&[^\s]*;/g, ''));
```

Note that this is pretty aggressive and might remove more text than you wish if your text is really badly encoded, with missing `;` for instance.